# android virtual keyboard listener

Tags: android

Though i have asked the question before but dint get any proper answer. I have an EditText when edit text is focused android virtual keyboard pops up, i have added Done button to the keyboard using ime option from property window. Now i want to perform some action by pressing the Done button. How to do this? Please any body help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you an do it by firest finding reference of edittext and than set belows code for ur edittext:

---

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();//do here your stuff f
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
  });
```

---

here i have taken editText name which is ref. editextbox which u added and you have to add actionId==type of ime options which u have setted