# Numeric EditText and TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have an decimal signed EditText (so it's impossible to write a comma). I put a TextWatcher on it but it only listen chars allowed to be written.

However I want to catch when the user tries to write a comma to show a toast.

How is it possible to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4766883/4625829), just changing the `actionId` for comma?

Comment: Do tell me if it works. I'm not entirely sure if there is an actionId for comma tho. Haven't tried it yet.

Comment: All write, I'll try that tomorrow thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried out the suggestion I made in the comments where you make use of `setOnEditorActionListener()` and instead of using the `actionId`, I used the `KeyEvent event` and checked it's value if it's equal to `KeyCode.KEYCODE_COMMA`. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Searched around the community and a lot of other site on how to do it, but the closest I can manage to do is to detect the `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

I think since the setting of your `EditText` is to already restrict the comma to be entered, the system itself is also ignoring it. One thing I don't get though is to why catch it if the user has no way of doing it?

What I suggest for this is to make use of **[hint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint)** (*if what I think of your use case is correct*) to inform the user on what is supposed to be entered for that specific `EditText`. Or you could try to create your own softkeyboard. :D

If you do, however, managed to find a workaround for this, do tell. I'm very much interested. :)

Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` (like you said), but then you could implement an if/else statement to check the values in the `EditText`. Here is an example of what you could do:
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
   @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(String.valueOf(s).contains(",")) {
            String editTextContent = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
            editText.setText(editTextContent.replace(",", ""));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a valid input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // User entered something valid
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

This will make it so that the user cannot enter a comma. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer but do you think it will work? Because, as I said, I put restrictions (decimal and signed number) and just to test I put a toast in the beforeTextChanged and only the numbers and the points were called.

Comment: Have you tested this? I think this wouldn't work, as already mentioned in Herel's post, he won't be able to type in the comma. So checking with a `TextWatcher` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Isn't that the goal? @Herel wants to catch when the user types in the comma. The TextWatcher watches for the the user types the comma.

Comment: The `TextWatcher` will detect changes for the value inside the `EditText`. Not if its typed. Since the comma is already restricted. If he types it in, the text value wouldn't change, and the `TextWatcher` will end up listening for something that can never happen.

Comment: I believe I misunderstood his question then. I thought he wanted to have commas with a `Toast` being displayed when it's typed.

Answer (score 1):

try this specify your character in your edit text
like this may it will help you
android:digits="abcde.....012345789"

Comment: good answer. What ever the digits you wanna write in EditText you can. Except those user can not enter any other digits.